# Are there existing maps of U.S. county boundaries?

Tags: data, carto, united-states

I'm relatively new to Carto and very new on the latest interface.

Is there a way to find and join an existing map of Arizona county boundaries to my own data file for the same counties?

Comment: Are you trying to find a dataset of Arizona county boundaries (e.g. shapefile) or a rendered map of the same?  If it is finding data that you are stuck on then that part of your question may be more on-topic at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. Look for `cb_2013_us_county_500k` in CARTO Data Library. But as @PolyGeo pointed out in his comment, there is another SE site to ask for open data.